# Dangling Sprite pointer member variable after Sprite::create()

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x

I am getting started with cocos2d-x and I am encountering a problem. Below code throws read access violation error at `s->getChildrenCount();`.

HelloWorldScene.h

```
class HelloWorld : public cocos2d::Layer
{
public:
    static cocos2d::Scene* createScene();
    virtual bool init();
    void update(float) override;
    CREATE_FUNC(HelloWorld);

private:
    cocos2d::Sprite* s;
};
```

HelloWorldScene.cpp

```
Scene* HelloWorld::createScene()
{
    auto scene = Scene::create();
    auto layer = HelloWorld::create();
    scene->addChild(layer);
    return scene;
}
bool HelloWorld::init()
{
    if ( !Layer::init() )
    {
        return false;
    }

    s = Sprite::create();
    this->scheduleUpdate();
    return true;
}
void HelloWorld::update(float delta)
{
    int k = s->getChildrenCount();
    ...
}
```

My guess is that `s` becomes a dangling pointer and it has something to do with reference counting. I read how reference counting works but I did not fully understand it.

How is it possible that sprite gets destroyed at the end of `init`? Who is doing it?

What is the proper way to solve this issue? Do `s->retain()` after `Sprite::create()` and add `HelloWorldScene` destructor with `s->release()`? If I do this, I don't see the benefit over using traditional C++ `new` and `delete`.

Answer (score 0):

First off, there's no dangling pointer, but the pointer that was created no longer exists and `s` is now a `nullptr`. This is why you get an access violation error when you try to access the `getChildrenCount()` method.

Objects created using `create()` methods will be evaluated to be released as soon as the method they're created in ends. This means if the object has no references and is not marked to be retained, the created object will be deconstructed. If you want this behaviour to change you have to call retain, and release respectively, like you already concluded.

One of the benefits of `s->retain()` and `s->release()`, or reference counting in general, versus using `new` and `delete` is that you don't have to worry about data membership outside your class ie. **when you call delete, are you sure the resource is not used anywhere any longer**? This question becomes unnecessary by using reference counting and the retain/release mechanism.

Comment: You are right, I made a mistake - this is a null pointer and not a dangling pointer. "Objects created using create() methods will be evaluated to be released as soon as the method they're created in ends." - How is this possible in C++?

Comment: That is a good question, but not easily answered in a comment. Try searching for C++ reference counting and smart pointers.